# How to fix elementor update causes Server error

Tags: wordpress, elementor

When i update my home page using elementor I am getting a server error (503 error). However, my other page updates seems to be fine. Can someone help me find out the root cause? where can i find the logs?

So far i tried,

1. Clear the cache
2. Enabled the editor load method in elementors advanced settings.
3. Deactivated and reactivated the elementor plugin.

[image]

***UPDATE: When using developer tools, i get these error upon clicking update.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

This link could help explain what's going on:
https://wordpress.org/support/topic/13-feb-update-elementor-error-503/

It recommends trying [Elementor safe mode](https://elementor.com/help/what-is-safe-mode/) first and foremost.

I would also recommend trying the operation that fails with your developer tools open. Right click on the page, select Inspect (or similar), the tools appear. Click the Network tab and then reload the page and restart the update process that fails. Look at the files being requested
[image: Inspector network tab]

If you see anything that turns red there, or a file that has any other http status code than 200, it may be the error right there. If you click on that file you may be able to get more information about why it doesn't load. Try the headers or response tabs in the panel that opens up.

Where your server logs are located depends on your website hosting service. Read on their pages where to locate them or get in touch with their customer service. Try to post the relevant part of the log here if you see something out of the ordinary.

Comment: Thanks for answering. Safe mode is not an option for me, because i cant test to update the page and it messes up my home page. So i tried using developer tools, and when i click update i got these errors. Updated the screenshot in the question.

Comment: I think I know what it is. They have moved /wp-admin so when you try to go to that link it's a 404. That means wp-ajax.php can't be found on that URL. You need to either reinstore or open up wp-admin at its original location or modify all urls pointing to it.

Comment: I have asked host provider and they checked my running processes and apparently my allocated resources are hitting the peak and causing the server to return 503 error. I have upgraded my plan and now with increased memory it seems fine now! Thanks for looking into it!

Answer (score 0):

just  add a single line in wp-config.php

define('WP_MEMORY_LIMIT','2048M');

Answer (score 0):

For a quick fix you can try elementor "safe mode" from elementor>tools>safe mode and then "enable".